# Disable Horizontal Scroll on Div

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

There is a cross browser dilemma especially now that safari uses an internal scroll mechanism that floats on top.

When a div with fixed height's content ends up getting larger than the div we need a scroll bar, but the scrollbar takes out some width and thus a horizontal bar is added to. How do we prevent a horizontal scroll even if the content is to wide I want no ability for the user to be able to scroll horizontally.

The CSS3 property overflow-x:hidden, still allows the user to scroll left and right with a trackpad. I want it disabled completely, or a solution that removes the problem of the vertical scroll bar taking width from the div.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: Can you provide us an example (on jsfiddle or anywhere else), where div with `overflow-x:hidden` can be scrolled in safari? Couldn't reproduce for myself.

Comment: Safari does not reproduce it but Firefox does as it's scrollbar cuts off from the width

Answer (score 2):

One solution is that you make the vertical scroll bar always display:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

But still the scroll bar's width doesn't stay the same across browsers.

Or you can make a custom scroll bar replacement with div/CSS/JavaScript. Here is a jQuery plugin which seems promising:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as background should fix your issues